# Downloads from IIS webserver behind proxy end before full file is downloaded if Content-Length isn't present in response

Tags: c#, http, iis

I have the following C# code that allows the user to download a file from a link in an ASP MVC website:

```
        protected byte[] Bytes { get; set; }    
        ...      
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        response.Clear();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FileName))
        {
            response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", FileName));
        }

        response.ContentType = ContentType ?? GetContentTypeFromFileExtension();

        response.BinaryWrite(Bytes ?? new byte[0]);
        response.End();
```

I use it to download .zip files. This works OK in my local environment, but when I host this in IIS running in a remote machine, *behind a proxy server*, the download finishes "early", leaving a corrupted file. The IIS version is 10.

If I add the following line to the code:

```
response.AddHeader("Content-Length", Bytes.Length.ToString());
```

The download continues until the file finishes downloading completely. I'm curious as to why this happens. For reference, the proxy server in my machine also runs, but is hosted in the same "server" as the webserver from which I'm downloading the file, unlike the remote environment where they are hosted in different servers.

This is the log entry IIS logs when the download "finishes" early:

```
date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status sc-bytes time-taken
2020-08-31 13:42:40 <IP> GET /Download/File/DownloadFile filePath=myfile.zip 4000 <ID> <ANOTHER_IP> Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/84.0.4147.135+Safari/537.36 https://example.com/path/to/function 200 0 1236 76251144 272121
```

The `sc-bytes` field is correct: that's the size of the file in bytes (around 72MB). However, the download "finishes" successfuly after 60MB.

Meanwhile, the proxy server registers this:

```
2020-08-31 13:42:41 <IP> GET /Download/File/DownloadFile&X-ARR-CACHE-HIT=0&X-ARR-LOG-ID=<ID>&SERVER-STATUS=200 443 - <ANOTHER_IP> Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/84.0.4147.135+Safari/537.36 https://example.com/path/to/function 502 3 12030 60819990 4796 278149
```

Fewer bytes sent, even though it finishes 1 second before.

Any one has any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: The code that works is probably using HTTP 1.0 which is stream mode where you get all data in one chunk.  On IIS you are probably using HTTP 1.1 which is chunk mode where you are getting data in chunks.  You can set in request HTTP 1.0 to force stream mode.  You can verify by using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and check which mode is being used.

Comment: @jdweng In both cases using Wireshark I see the data being sent in chunks.

Comment: Maybe you are reaching a limit or getting CRC errors.  Do you always get the same wrong size?  HTTP is composed of one or more TCP datagrams.  The TCP datagrams are ~1500 bytes each.  So you can see if you are getting [FIN] in the TCP to see if connection is getting closed.  Also you can check the Sequence number of the TCP to see if you are getting any datagrams getting resent.

Answer (score 1):

Any HTTP client, server, or proxy can close a TCP transport connection at any time. The connections normally are closed at the end of a message, but during error conditions, the connection may be closed in the middle of a header line or in other strange places.

This situation is common. HTTP applications are free to close persistent connections after any period of time.

so If the body was preceded by a Content-Length header, the client MUST close the connection at that time.

also, try to set the [connection Timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/sitedefaults/limits) value by using iis site advance setting and check to [keep-alive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpprotocol/) setting.

Comment: so the proxy server was closing the connection when the file download didn't have the Content-Length header because of timeout but when I added the Content-Length header it didn't because that gave it the information to wait until it's done?